# Rotate portrait to landscape and portrait mode of my view controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-orientation

Normally my application shows all views in portrait mode except report view. Report view shows only when I am on settings view and I rotate my device to landscape mode. Now when I rotate my device to portrait mode again, report view is dismissed and settings view is displayed.

```
In report view 

> shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)||( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft));



Here at settings view 

    shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation


    if((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)||( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
     {  

     Report *report = [[Report alloc]initWithNibName:@"Report" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:report animated:YES];
     [report release];

     }
     return YES;
     }
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? Are you able to see your report view in landscape mode? If yes, please explain about the next step you need.

Comment: I will be able to help you only if I understand you question well. But you are not able to explain it to me in proper english. That's y I tried to modify your question, in a way, I understood your question. Please read the modified question again and let me know if I am interpreting things right?

Answer (score 1):

Don't create your viewcontroller in shouldRotate..., but in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, which is where you're supposed to respond to a rotation. In your `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, just return YES when you want to be able to rotate to that orientation- in your case, it looks like you want to either all orientations, or all orientations except PortraitUpsideDown.

In your `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, you can push your viewcontroller or pop it as needed.